# Perl weird result when printing hash key

Tags: perl, hash, key

```
my $dat;
$dat{"1","1","1","1","1"}{'CR'} = "2";

foreach my $k1 (keys %dat){
    print $k1;
}
```

This is my code and it should be no problem and can execute in other computer but my laptop show this result 
[image]

It compile with no error..... can somone tell me what happen?  Is it less certain module?

Comment: Unrelated to the actual question, but note that `$dat{...}` accesses the variable `%dat`, *not* `$dat`. `my $dat` should, therefore, be `my %dat` instead. (If you had `use strict` enabled, it would have caught that for you.) Aside from that, I am not able to reproduce your output - I get `11111`.

Comment: that my mistake but still i think should can produce 11111 but i not sure y it print something weird

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may want to check [`perlvar`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24%3b)

> $;
>   The subscript separator for multidimensional array emulation. If you refer to a hash element as
>
> ```
> $foo{$a,$b,$c}
> ```
>
> it really means
>
> ```
> $foo{join($;, $a, $b, $c)}
> ```

Default is `\034`, the same as SUBSEP in awk. If your keys contain binary data there might not be any safe value for `$;`.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %dat;
$dat{"1","1","1","1","1"}{'CR'} = "2";
# which is equivalent to
# my $k = join($;, "1","1","1","1","1");
# $dat{$k}{'CR'} = "2";

foreach my $k1 (keys %dat){
    print "$_\n" for map { $_ eq $; ? '$;' : $_ } split //, $k1;
}
```

output

```
1
$;
1
$;
1
$;
1
$;
1
```

Answer (score 2):

Your hash does not contain what you think it contains.  Specifically, it has only a single key:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl    

use strict;
use warnings;

my %dat;
$dat{"1","1","1","1","1"}{'CR'} = "2";

use Data::Dumper; 
print Dumper \%dat
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = {
          '11111' => {
                           'CR' => '2'
                         }
        };
```

As suggested by Сухой27, the `1`s in the key are concatenated using the value of `$;` as a separator:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl    

use strict;
use warnings;

$; = '---';

my %dat;
$dat{"1","1","1","1","1"}{'CR'} = "2";

use Data::Dumper; 
print Dumper \%dat
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = {
          '1---1---1---1---1' => {
                                   'CR' => '2'
                                 }
        };
```

Change `$;` to an empty string, and you'll get `11111` as output, as I assume you're expecting.